# Dynamic filtering in D3 with HTML input

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, filtering

I am far to be a D3 geek and just made one of my first 'scatter plots' reading from a tab delimited file. Each dot (or circle) has a date (x axis) and a count (y axis) attached to it and a sentence, which shows on mouseover. The code and tab file containing the data are here:

https://gist.github.com/sytpp/3a070a6ed6834169a85b

I added a text box where I can enter a search term (line 39-42), when I hit 'Tell me' I would like it to highlight all dots which match the search term in column 2 (who) and/or 3 (what) of the data. I managed to change the opacity of ALL dots (including legend) upon search (line 193-201) but didn't figure out how to select a subsect dynamically based on text match.

```
function handleClick(event){
    console.log(document.getElementById("myVal").value)
    draw(document.getElementById("myVal").value)
return false;
}

function draw(val){
    d3.select("body").selectAll("circle").style("opacity", .3);
}
```

I found similar examples on flowingdata but could not reproduce it. Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: If you have the data bound to each circle the typical pattern is d3.select("body").selectAll("circle").style("opacity", function(d) { ...//here comes your logic based on which you return a certain opacity...;})

Comment: so I added the handleClick and the draw function inside the function where the data d is available but I get this error when I hit search: referenceError: handleClick is not defined.

Comment: yes, the function call of handleClick has keep global scope since it's called from the form. See my answer below - hope that helps!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your visualization is really cool! I looked at your code and you just have to make some minor changes:

First of all, your current function draw() contains the wrong selection.

```
d3.select("body").selectAll("circle").style("opacity", .3);
```

It contains not just the circles in the graph but also the circles from the legend!. So when you draw the circles in the graph, assign a proper class name to them:

```
svg.selectAll("circle.dot")                                    
    .data(data)                                            
    .enter()...
```

So in the function draw, you can get the right selection with:

```
d3.select("body").selectAll("circle.dot")
```

For setting the opacity for the circles matching the search you just write the logic in the callback function. I separated the callback (and stored the search term in a global variable) ...

```
var valOpacity = function(d) { 
      if ((d.what.search(currentSearchTerm) != -1) || (d.who.search(currentSearchTerm) != -1)) {
        return 1;
      }
      else {
        return 0.1;
      }
    };
```

because we can reuse this first for the very selection...

```
function draw(){
    d3.select("body").selectAll("circle.dot").style("opacity", valOpacity);
}
```

... and second to adapt your mouseout event to set the opacity correctly:

```
.on("mouseout", function(){
        d3.select(this).transition().duration(50).attr("r", 5).style("opacity", valOpacity); 
    });
```

Here is the full working code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style> /* set the CSS */

body { font: 16px Arial;}

path { 
    stroke: steelblue;
    stroke-width: 2;
    fill: none;
}

.axis path,
.axis line {
    fill: none;
    stroke: grey;
    stroke-width: 1;
    shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

div.tooltip {
    position: absolute;    
    text-align: left; 
    width: 300px;    
    height: 150px;        
    padding: 2px;    
    font: 16px Arial;   
    background: none;    
    border: 0px;                    
    border-radius: 2px;
}



</style>
<body>

<form name="myform" onSubmit="return handleClick()">
        <input type="text" id="myVal" placeholder="Search WHO should do WHAT">
        <input name="Submit"  type="submit" value="Tell me!" >
</form>  

<!-- load the d3.js library -->    
<script type=
    "text/javascript" src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js">
</script>

<script>

// Set the dimensions of the canvas / graph
var margin = {top: 30, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 60},
    width = 800 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 600 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

// Parse the date / time
var parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d").parse;
var formatTime = d3.time.format("%d %B %Y");// Format tooltip date / time

var currentSearchTerm = "";

// Set the rangestrann
var x = d3.time.scale().range([0, width]);
var y = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]);

var flags = ["LEADERS","LETTERS,BRIEFINGS,ETC...","INTERNATIONAL","ASIA (incl. CHINA)","AMERICAS", "EUROPE (incl. BRITAIN)","BUSINESS"]
var cols = ["#b2182b","#969696","#252525","#08519c","#fec503","#5aae61","#de77ae" ]

var color = d3.scale.ordinal().domain(flags).range(cols);

// Define the axes
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x)
    .orient("bottom").ticks(5);

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y)
    .orient("left").ticks(5);


// Define 'div' for tooltips
var div = d3.select("body")
    .append("div")  // declare the tooltip div 
    .attr("class", "tooltip")
    .style("opacity", 0);

// Adds the svg canvas
var svg = d3.select("body")
    .append("svg")
        .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
        .attr("transform", 
              "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");


// Legend              
var legend = d3.select("body").append("svg")
                    .attr("width",200)
                    .attr("height",200)
                    .append("g")
                        .attr("transform","translate(10,14)");


legend.append("circle").attr("cx", 10).attr("cy", 10).style("fill", cols[0]).attr("r", 20).style("opacity", .7);
    legend.append("text").attr("x", 40).attr("y",16).style("font-size","15px").text("Click to read article.");

legend.append("circle").attr("cx", 10).attr("cy", 55).style("fill", cols[6]).attr("r", 5);
    legend.append("text").attr("x", 25).attr("y",60).style("font-size","12px").text(flags[6]);

legend.append("circle").attr("cx", 10).attr("cy", 70).style("fill", cols[5]).attr("r", 5);
    legend.append("text").attr("x", 25).attr("y",75).style("font-size","12px").text(flags[5]);

legend.append("circle").attr("cx", 10).attr("cy", 85).style("fill", cols[4]).attr("r", 5);
    legend.append("text").attr("x", 25).attr("y",90).style("font-size","12px").text(flags[4]);

legend.append("circle").attr("cx", 10).attr("cy", 100).style("fill", cols[3]).attr("r", 5);
    legend.append("text").attr("x", 25).attr("y",105).style("font-size","12px").text(flags[3]);

legend.append("circle").attr("cx", 10).attr("cy", 115).style("fill", cols[2]).attr("r", 5);
    legend.append("text").attr("x", 25).attr("y",120).style("font-size","12px").text(flags[2]);

legend.append("circle").attr("cx", 10).attr("cy", 130).style("fill", cols[1]).attr("r", 5);
    legend.append("text").attr("x", 25).attr("y",135).style("font-size","12px").text(flags[1]);

legend.append("circle").attr("cx", 10).attr("cy", 145).style("fill", cols[0]).attr("r", 5);
    legend.append("text").attr("x", 25).attr("y",150).style("font-size","12px").text(flags[0]);


// Get the data
d3.tsv("EcoSHOULDS.tab", function(error, data) {

    data.forEach(function(d) {
        d.date = parseDate(d.date);
    });

    // Scale the range of the data
    x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.date; }));
    y.domain([0,50]);


    // draw the scatterplot
    svg.selectAll("circle.dot")                                    
        .data(data)                                            
        .enter()
        .append("a")
            .attr("xlink:href", function(d) { return d.link; })
        .append("circle")
          .attr("class", "dot")
            .attr("r", 5)    
            .attr("cx", function(d) { return x(d.date); })         
            .attr("cy", function(d) { return y(d.lala); })
            .attr("fill", function(d){ return color(d.flag); })

    // MOUSEOVER EVENTS - Tooltip stuff after this etc
        .on("mouseover", function(d) {   

        d3.select(this).transition().duration(50).attr("r", 20).style("opacity", .7); 


            div.transition()
                .duration(500)    
                .style("fill", 0);
            div.transition()
                .duration(200)    
                .style("opacity", 1);    
            div .html(
                d.who + "<br/><b><big>SHOULD</big></b><br/>" + 
                d.what + "..." + "<br/><br/><small>" + 
                formatTime(d.date) + "  [ Section: " + 
                d.flag + " ]</small><br/>")     
                .style("left", 810 + "px")             
                .style("top", 100 + "px");
            })

        .on("mouseout", function(){
                d3.select(this).transition().duration(50).attr("r", 5).style("opacity", valOpacity); 
            });

    // Add the X Axis
    svg.append("g")    
        .attr("class", "x axis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
        .call(xAxis);

    // Add the Y Axis
    svg.append("g")    
        .attr("class", "y axis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(-30," + 0 + ")")
        .call(yAxis);

});


function handleClick(event){
  currentSearchTerm = document.getElementById("myVal").value;
    console.log(currentSearchTerm);
    draw(currentSearchTerm);
return false;
}

var valOpacity = function(d) { 
      if ((d.what.search(currentSearchTerm) != -1) || (d.who.search(currentSearchTerm) != -1)) {
        return 1;
      }
      else {
        return 0.1;
      }
    };

function draw(){
    d3.select("body").selectAll("circle.dot").style("opacity", valOpacity);
}

</script>
</body>
```

Comment: Yes, it works like a charm! Great! Thanks also for taking the time to explain it so well - it really helps!

Comment: @Sylvia: I am glad I could help. When you want to undo a filter on a search term, just delete the search term hit the button and it will show everything. If you want to add some spice to it, you could add a couple of lines to make the transition to the filtered dots accompanied by the dots transitioning to a bigger circles and then pop back to their size. Anyway, keep up the great work and have fun with d3.js and stackoverflow!